# UPDATE on JIRA jql

Tags: jira, jql

I need to update the status in a project on jira. Can i make it like on SQL, or something similar ?
UPDATE PROJECT= ___ SET status = "___" WHERE Created <= 2021-09-30;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do a search, go to Tools, Bulk Change and then Transition issues